Get-AzureADUser with multiple pipes
Today I'm retrieving our Entra ID users using this code snippet:
Get-AzureADUser -All $true -Filter "UserType eq 'Member'"| Select-Object -Property $args[0] | Where-Object {($_.DirSyncEnabled -eq 'True')}

Later in my script I am using a code snippet I found on Google to retrieve license status for each user:
Get-AzureAdUser -ObjectId $Object.ObjectId | ForEach{ $licensed=$False;
 
For ($i=0; $i -le ($_.AssignedLicenses | Measure).Count ; $i++)
    { 
    If( [string]::IsNullOrEmpty( $_.AssignedLicenses[$i].SkuId ) -ne $True) { $licensed='Active' } 
    }; 
    If( $licensed -eq $false)
    { $licensed='Inactive'} 
}

But I would like to retrieve all data from Azure one time so I am trying to combine these two into one query.
If I just combine the pipe I doesn't retrieve any data. Just blank.
I was thinking of combining them both and instead of just putting the value into an variable add new psobject for each user. Like:
Get-AzureAdUser -ObjectId $Object.ObjectId | ForEach{ 

    $licensed=$False;
 
    For ($i=0; $i -le ($_.AssignedLicenses | Measure).Count ; $i++) { 
        If( [string]::IsNullOrEmpty( $_.AssignedLicenses[$i].SkuId ) -ne $True) { 
            $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "LicenseStatus" -Value "Active" 
        } 
    }; 
    If( $licensed -eq $false) { 
        $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "LicenseStatus" -Value "Inactive" 
    } 
}


Do you want to perform the operation with multiple pipes or a normal PowerShell is okay to retrieve the information?

Doesn't need to be multiple pipes but at my understanding it is needed in order to retrieve all data and add them to psobjects but this is far over my understanding in how to build the query.

Do you want to get all Entra users and their assigned licenses using PowerShell script?

Check if this works for you

you should consider migrating your code to MS Graph, Azure AD is in process of deprecation. in addition, what you want to achieve can be done by fully leveraging the OData filter: $filter=assignedLicenses/$count ne 0 and userType eq 'Member' and onPremisesSyncEnabled eq true

To retrieve all Microsoft Entra ID users (synchronized from on-premises) along with their License status, make use of below PowerShell script:
# Retrieve all Azure AD users who are members and synchronized from on-premises
$users = Get-AzureADUser -All $true -Filter "UserType eq 'Member'" | Where-Object { $_.DirSyncEnabled -eq $true }

$results = @()
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $licensed = $false
   
    foreach ($license in $user.AssignedLicenses) {
        if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($license.SkuId)) {
            $licensed = 'Active'
            break
        }
    }
    
    if ($licensed -eq $false) {
        $licensed = 'Inactive'
    }

        $userObject = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        DisplayName   = $user.DisplayName
        UserPrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName
        LicenseStatus = $licensed
    }
    
    $results += $userObject
}

$results



If you want to retrieve all Microsoft Entra ID users along with their License status, make use of below PowerShell script:
# Retrieve all Azure AD users who are members 
$users = Get-AzureADUser -All $true -Filter "UserType eq 'Member'" 

$results = @()
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $licensed = $false
   
    foreach ($license in $user.AssignedLicenses) {
        if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($license.SkuId)) {
            $licensed = 'Active'
            break
        }
    }
    
    if ($licensed -eq $false) {
        $licensed = 'Inactive'
    }

        $userObject = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        DisplayName   = $user.DisplayName
        UserPrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName
        LicenseStatus = $licensed
    }
    
    $results += $userObject
}

$results


